# How to use a Nested object as a query parameter for Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper, nested-object

I am using Dapper instead of Entity Framework. I experienced an error when I tried using a nested 
object as a query parameter.

The error looks like this :

> The member of Device of Type App.Model.Device cannot be used as a parameter value.

If there is anything I can improve on my question structure do comment.
Don't Bash.
Thanks

I have classes that look like this:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public Device device { get; set; }
    public long time { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }
}
public class Device
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

And A SQL insert Query which looks something like this:

```
private const string InsertQuery = @"Insert into iot.[Table] (DeviceID,DeviceData,UnixTime) values(@device.id,@data,@time)";
```

The dapper Insert function:

```
  public CreateCommand(List<Datum> Datums)
        {
            _Datums = Datums;
        }
        public void Execute()
        {
            Insert();
        }
        private void Insert()
        {
            using (var connection = DatabaseConfiguration.SqlServer())
            {
                using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connection.Execute(InsertQuery, _Datums, transaction);
                        transaction.Commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Any solutions yet?

Answer (score 0):

*updated answer

```
var ro = RootObject.Init(cnnStr, commandTimeout: 100); 
Device dev = new Device{id="123456"} 
long unixtime = long unixTimestamp = (long)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1,> 1))).TotalSeconds; 
Datum dat = new Datum{device=dev,time=unixtime,data="abcdef"}; 
dat.id = ro.Datum.Insert(dat);
```

or,

```
string insertQuery = @"Insert into iot.[Table] (DeviceID,DeviceData,UnixTime) values(@id,@data,@time)";

    var result = db.Execute(insertQuery, new
    {
        Device.ID,
        strData,
        (DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds
    });
```

Comment: oh that why just a typo in the question. Thanks for pointing it out though. However the problem still persist

Comment: Ill update my question with dapper just to clarify which framework im using.